# Async SSBO Readback

Tags: opengl, compute-shader, shader-storage-buffer, ssbo

When I call GetBufferSubData with my Shader Storage Buffer Object there is typically a 4ms delay. Is it possible for my application to do work during that time?

```
// start GetBufferSubData
// do client/app/CPU work
// (wait if needed)
// read results from GetBufferSubData
```

Or otherwise use some sort of API to asynchronously start copying buffer data from the GPU?

I was able to get an async readback working using `glMapBufferRange` and `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT`. However, when running a compute shader (multiple times back to back) on that buffer, this results in a massive performance degradation compared to no persistent mapping.

Comment: "*It shows as being extremely performance intensive on my GPU.*" What exactly is "performance intensive"? Persistent mapping is something you do *once*; that's why it's called "persistent". You map the buffer and just use the pointer whenever you need to.

Comment: With the persistent mapping, ALL values are being copied back and forth, so there are bandwidth issues. I need to be able to obtain sub ranges only.

Comment: "*With the persistent mapping, ALL values are being copied back and forth*" Nonsense. If you map persistently, *nothing* is copied. You have a pointer to the storage in question. That's it. If you copy something, it's because you copied it by reading from the pointer.

Comment: Here was my understanding: The SSBO data is on the GPU.
Reading any of that data requires copying it into RAM. The mapped part is just a copy of it in RAM (that could even be out of date). The data on the GPU is being modified by a shader. So when does that transfer take place with a persistently mapped buffer? When is that transfer time paid to move from GPU to RAM?

Comment: "*The mapped part is just a copy of it in RAM*" That's not what persistent mapping is. When you persistently map a buffer, your pointer is a CPU-addressable pointer to the GPU's memory for that storage. Any reading happens when you dereference that pointer, just like it would for any other CPU read of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with simply marking the buffer with `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` was that this resulted in a substantial performance degradation (8x slower) when running a compute shader on that buffer (profiled using Nvidia Nsight Graphics). I suspect this is because of the mapping, OpenGL needs to read/write the buffer into a different location that is less performant on the GPU, but more performant/accessible by the CPU.

My solution was to create a much smaller buffer (1000x smaller, 16kb) that is persistently mapped that the CPU can use to read/write to the larger buffer in small increments when needed. This combination was much faster with only a minor API overhead that achieved my needs.